# Powershell subsettimg square brackets NOT condition

Tags: powershell

I have this array as shown here

```
$files=1..10
```

I want to return everything except for the **4th object**

Is there a simpler way instead of this?
This works but I think there has to be a easier way.

```
$files[0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: I tried $files[0..2,4..9] but failes

Comment: Like `$files[0..2 + 4..($files.Length - 1)]` but not sure how much easier that is. There is nothing like Python's slicing in Pwsh. Its kinda cumbersome

Comment: Yeah that seems more complicated but thanks for trying !

Comment: What about `$files | Select-Object -SkipIndex 4` ? But `-SkipIndex` is only available in newer versions of PowerShell (Core)

Comment: `$files[0..2+4..9]`

Comment: this works, I didn't see this solution until now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/) the easiest solution is to use [`Select-Object -SkipIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#-skipindex) i.e.:

```bash
$files = 1..10
$files | Select-Object -SkipIndex 1, 2, 4

3
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Otherwise, if you want to do it via [indexing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#index-operator--) the solution is more cumbersome:

```bash
# if you want to do it dynamically (not hardcoding the index of the last element)
$files[0..2 + 4..($files.Length - 1)]
```

If you don't want to or can't install the latest version of PowerShell and still would like to have the same `-SkipIndex` functionality as demonstrated above, you could have your own wrapper around `Select-Object` with a [SteppablePipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.getsteppablepipeline?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) and store the wrapper in your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#profile) so it gets loaded every time you start a new session. Note that this code is autogenerated using the [`ProxyCommand` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.proxycommand?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) and the only added logic to it is:

- In `begin` block:

```bash
if($withSkipIndex = $PSBoundParameters.Remove('SkipIndex')) {
    $i = 1
}
```

- In `process` block:

```bash
if($withSkipIndex -and $i++ -in $SkipIndex) {
    return
}
```

Wrapper Code:

```bash
function Select-Object2 {
    [CmdletBinding(
        DefaultParameterSetName='DefaultParameter',
        HelpUri='https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2096716',
        RemotingCapability='None'
    )]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [psobject]
        ${InputObject},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='DefaultParameter', Position=0)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='SkipLastParameter', Position=0)]
        [System.Object[]]
        ${Property},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='DefaultParameter')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='SkipLastParameter')]
        [string[]]
        ${ExcludeProperty},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='DefaultParameter')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='SkipLastParameter')]
        [string]
        ${ExpandProperty},

        [switch]
        ${Unique},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='DefaultParameter')]
        [ValidateRange(0, 2147483647)]
        [int]
        ${Last},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='DefaultParameter')]
        [ValidateRange(0, 2147483647)]
        [int]
        ${First},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='DefaultParameter')]
        [ValidateRange(0, 2147483647)]
        [int]
        ${Skip},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='SkipLastParameter')]
        [ValidateRange(0, 2147483647)]
        [int]
        ${SkipLast},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='DefaultParameter')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='IndexParameter')]
        [switch]
        ${Wait},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='IndexParameter')]
        [ValidateRange(0, 2147483647)]
        [int[]]
        ${Index},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='SkipIndexParameter')]
        [ValidateRange(0, 2147483647)]
        [int[]]
        ${SkipIndex}
    )

    begin {
        $outBuffer = $null
        if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer)) {
            $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
        }

        if($withSkipIndex = $PSBoundParameters.Remove('SkipIndex')) {
            $i = 1
        }

        $wrappedCmd = Get-Command 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Select-Object'
        $scriptCmd  = { & $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }

        $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
        $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
    }

    process {
        if($withSkipIndex -and $i++ -in $SkipIndex) {
            return
        }
        $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
    }
    end {
        $steppablePipeline.End()
    }
}
```

Usage is exactly the same as `Select-Object`:

```bash
$files | Select-Object2 -SkipIndex 1, 2, 4

3
5
6
7
8
9
10
```